# What is the criteria for selecting the range in normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normalization, feature-scaling

Generally the range is 0 to 1. But I have read papers where different ranges are used Say 1 to 7.
I want to know the logic behind this.

Comment: Every problem has its own logic in normalisation although there are typical ones. Maybe you can share the paper that uses the range 1-7 and we can have an understanding why they choose to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If by "normalization" you mean "scaling" than the idea behind this procedure is to ensure that all your variables lie in the same range and have the same importance for the model.

For example, if you measure your distance in feet and the velocity in m/h - the influence that distance will have would be roughly 0.3 of the influence that the velocity will have.

The common practice for scaling is to make all the features lie in range of [0, 1], but it doesn't really matter in terms of performance, (i.e. you could make all your variables range from 100 to 200 and the performance would be the same), it's only important to scale all of your variables (by all I mean numeric variables off course).

Hope that helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If your output activation function has a range of [0,1], then obviously you must ensure that the target values lie within that range. But it is generally better to choose an output activation function suited to the distribution of the targets than to force your data to conform to the output activation function.

Comment: There is absolutely no connection between the activation function and the range of the variable. Your variables can, and usually will be much larger than 1, and in case of Neural Networks where you apply the activation to the weighted sum of the inputs (i.e. the variables) it most probably will be several magnitudes larger than 1. In the end, what "squashes" those values to the [0,1] interval is the activation itself, be it sigmoid, ReLu or other activation function.

Comment: lets assume you scaled target variable in between 0 and 5 and you are using  activation funtion sigmoid .In each iteration of the neural network ,it is comparing the predicted value having  range [0,1] with actual value between [0,5].Did u think it is  fair.

Comment: I see your point of confusion there. The thing is that scaling is applied on the features, not on the target variable, which in case on regression will have a real measured value, and in case of classification will be a 1-hot-vector (1 for the class index, 0 for the rest). In your example, if you can use a target in range of [0, 5] (i.e. in case of 5 classes, or for regression for predicting a real  value in range [0, 5]), but your activation will not be a function that outputs values in [0, 1], but it has nothing to do with scaling - it's just how the learning process  works.